# next previous button in div jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i have a total of 11 div in my app. what i want to do is to display 3 divs in between 2 permanent div it should look like this

|first permanent div| |div 1| |div 2| |div 3| |second permanent div|

|previous| |next|

when i click on next is should look like this

|first permanent div| |div 2| |div 3| |div 4| |second permanent div|

|previous| |next|

and so on. and when im in div 1,2,3 the previous should be disabled and when im in 7,8,9 the next should be disabled.

but i cant make it i'm using this fiddle as a sample http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/1/ its working but only one div is shown in the center of my two permanent div which is not in my plan.im getting like this

|first permanent div| |div 1| |second permanent div|

|previous| |next|

any suggestion will be taken seriously.

here is the code of the fiddle im working on as tutorial

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().show();
    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    });
    $("button[name=prev]").click(function (e) {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // or .css('display','block');
        //console.log(divs.length, now);
    });
});

<div class="mydivs">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont u think your question is messed up!

Comment: done editing.sorry about the messed up question

Comment: you can use the jquery plugin "pajinate". its super easy and has enough options for your requirements as long the two permantent divs arent something like crazy dynamic stuff.

Comment: you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/R7FYb/

Comment: or this with animation. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y3yfE/

Comment: @Omar they are both cool is there way that the div are side by side not on top so the movements are from left to right?i tried to do things with it but it didn't work.

Comment: It's a css issue, not a big deal :)

Comment: lol i tried changing top to left/right didnt work now i know i was way off the target.

Comment: right to left http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nENUs/

Comment: really nice @Omar il make it work from left to right

Answer (score 0):

you should create this divs like this:

```
 <div id="container">
        <div id="parment1" class="param">Here Perment 1</div>
        <div id="mydivs" class="mydivs">
            <div id=1 >1</div>
            <div id=2 >2</div>
            <div id=3 >3</div>
            <div id=4 >4</div>
            <div id=5 >5</div>
        </div>
        <div id="parment2" class="param">Here Perment 2</div>
    </div>
<button name="prev">go to previous div</button>
<button name="next">go to next div</button>
```

Then you jquery code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numToShow = 3;  // this param will control how many div to show
    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide();
    for(i = 0 ; i < numToShow ; i++)
    {
        if( i+1 >= divs.length )
        {
            break;
        }
        divs.eq(i).show();
    }

    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {
        divs = $('.mydivs>div');
        divs.eq(now).appendTo(".mydivs");
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        divs.eq(now+numToShow).show(); // show next
    });
    $("button[name=prev]").click(function (e) {
        divs = $('.mydivs>div');
        divs.eq(divs.length - 1).show(); // show next
        divs.eq(now+numToShow-1).hide();
        $(".mydivs").prepend(divs.eq(divs.length - 1));

        //now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;

    });
```

Add this css also:

```
.mydivs {
    height:300;
    border:5px solid #ccf;
}
.mydivs>div {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    border:5px solid #ff0;
    padding:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.param{
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    border:5px solid #ff0;
    padding:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
}

#container{
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: this works exactly as the fiddle of omar at the top.it moves from top to bottom